# How can I pass the keyword from API? (React and Django)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am new to react so pretty much stuck here. I tried to follow a search functionality for my filtering function. I already make the api for filtering and it is working perfectly.
In django when I go to my url it is showing me right products. My django url is like http://localhost:8000/api/products/category/?keyword1=1

I want to do the same for some button and will add the link like, category/?keyword1=1

I am sharing my code.

#this is my action for category

```
export const categoryListProducts = (keyword1 = '') => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_CATEGORY_LIST_REQUEST })

        const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/category/${keyword1}`)

        dispatch({
            type: PRODUCT_CATEGORY_LIST_SUCCESS,
            payload: data
        })
    }catch(error){
        dispatch({
            type: PRODUCT_CATEGORY_LIST_FAIL,
            payload: error.response && error.response.data.detail
            ? error.response.data.detail
            : error.message,
        })
    }
}
```

#this is my reducer

```
export const categoryProductListReducer = (state = { products: [], p: [] }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case PRODUCT_CATEGORY_LIST_REQUEST:
            return { loading: true, products: []}
        
        case PRODUCT_CATEGORY_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return { loading: false, products: action.payload }

        case PRODUCT_CATEGORY_LIST_FAIL:
            return { loading: false, error: action.payload }


        default:
            return state

    }
}
```

#this is my category screen

```
function CategoryScreen({history}) {


    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const productList = useSelector(state => state.productList)
    const {error, loading, products} = productList


    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(categoryListProducts())
        params: {  }
    }, [dispatch])


    return (
        <div>
            {loading ? <Loader />
                : error ? <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>
                    :
                    <Row className='flex flex-wrap' >

                            {products.map(product => (
                                <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                                    <Product product={product} />
                                </Col>
                            ))}
                    </Row>  
            } 
        </div>
    )
}

export default CategoryScreen
```

and this is the route

```
 <Route path='/category' component={CategoryScreen} />
```

for more info I am sharing my api call

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def getP(request):

    query = request.query_params.get('keyword1')
    if query == None:
        query = ''

    products = Product.objects.all().filter(category__id__iexact=query)
    serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note that Redux will pass `dispatch` argument to the thunk function for dispatching actions.**

```
export const categoryListProducts = (keyword1 = '') => 
return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_CATEGORY_LIST_REQUEST })

        const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/category/${keyword1}`)

        dispatch({
            type: PRODUCT_CATEGORY_LIST_SUCCESS,
            payload: data
        })
    }catch(error){
        dispatch({
            type: PRODUCT_CATEGORY_LIST_FAIL,
            payload: error.response && error.response.data.detail
            ? error.response.data.detail
            : error.message,
        })
    }
}
```

also you can pass `keyword1` as argument to this action `categoryListProducts()`

```
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(categoryListProducts('pass keyword1 here'))
        params: {  }
    }, [])
```

**Search Input**

```
 const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = React.useState("");
  const handleChange = event => {
        dispatch(categoryListProducts(event.target.value))
    setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
  };

or
   useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(categoryListProducts(searchTerm))
    }, [searchTerm])

    <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search"
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
```

Comment: it is telling me keyword1 not defined

Comment: declare it and pass the value as arguments